# Recomposition does not happen on change of value of mutableList()

Tags: android, state, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a `LazyColumn` to populate items on my screen. I have  a `mutablelist`(), and a `Text` composable, which is a part of a `LazyColumn` item, is created based on the value of my mutable list for the index of that item. But on using debugger, it's clear that my `Text` composable is not getting recomposed on change of value of mutable list. This  is my code:

```
        var listItemsOpen = remember { mutableListOf<Boolean>() }
        listItemsOpen.clear()
        for (i in 0..17){
            listItemsOpen.add(i, false)
        }

        LazyColumn(Modifier
                .constrainAs(listQuestions)
                {
                    start.linkTo(glListQuestionsLeft)
                    end.linkTo(glListQuestionsRight)
                    top.linkTo(glListQuestionsTop)
                    bottom.linkTo(glListQuestionsBottom)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                    height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
                .alpha(if (isAnyCategoryClicked) 1f
                else 0f))
        {
            itemsIndexed(if (txtToDisplay == "GENERAL") listGeneral
             else if (txtToDisplay == "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY") listPrivacy
            else if (txtToDisplay == "MY MONEY") listMyMoney
            else if (txtToDisplay == "WITHDRAWAL") listWithdrawal
            else listVoodleeAccSet
            ) { index, item ->
                Column(
                        Modifier
                                .padding(
                                        start = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._9sdp) },
                                        end = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._9sdp) },
                                        top = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12sdp) },
                                        bottom = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12sdp) },
                                )
                                .clickable {
                                    listItemsOpen[index] = !listItemsOpen[index]


                                    if (listItemsOpen[index]) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                            listItemsOpen.replaceAll { false }
                                        }
                                        listItemsOpen[index] = true

                                    }
                                }
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .background(Color(0xFF000000))
                )
                {

                    Box(Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(
                                    start = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._9sdp) },
                                    end = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._9sdp) },
                                    top = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12sdp) },
                                    bottom = with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12sdp) },
                            )) {
                        Text(
                                text = if (txtToDisplay == "GENERAL") stringResource(id = R.string.general_que1)
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY") stringResource(
                                        id = R.string.privacy_que1
                                )
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "MY MONEY") stringResource(id = R.string.my_money_que1)
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "WITHDRAWAL") stringResource(id = R.string.withdrawal_que1)
                                else stringResource(id = R.string.voodlee_acc_set_que1),
                                color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                                fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                                    dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()
                                },
                                fontFamily = FontFamily(
                                        Font(R.font.poppins_regular)
                                ),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                modifier = Modifier.align(CenterStart)
                        )

                        Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_faq_dn),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                        .align(CenterEnd)
                                        .height(with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._22sdp) })
                                        .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._22sdp) }),
                                contentDescription = "ic down"
                        )

                        Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_faq_up),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                        .align(CenterEnd)
                                        .height(with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._22sdp) })
                                        .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._22sdp) }),
                                contentDescription = "ic up"
                        )

                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(with(LocalDensity.current) {
                        dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._6sdp)
                    }))


               **//BELOW TEXT COMPOSABLE IS NOT GETTING RECOMPOSED**

                    if (listItemsOpen[index]) {

                        Text(
                                text = if (txtToDisplay == "GENERAL") stringResource(id = R.string.general_ans1)
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY") stringResource(id = R.string.privacy_ans1)
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "MY MONEY") stringResource(id = R.string.my_money_ans1)
                                else if (txtToDisplay == "WITHDRAWAL") stringResource(id = R.string.withdrawal_ans1)
                                else stringResource(id = R.string.voodlee_acc_set_ans1),
                                color = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                                fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                                    dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()
                                },
                                fontFamily = FontFamily(
                                        Font(R.font.poppins_light)
                                ),
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How do I  make the above `Text` recompose when the value of mutable list for that index changes?

Comment: what is txtToDisplay?

Comment: It is the text to be displayed as the header (which is above my LazyColumn)

Comment: Actually I have 5 cards. Each card has header text like "GENERAL", "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY" etc. When the user clicks any card, I store the header text of that card in "txtToDisplay", and use it's value as the header of 1st card and hide rest of the cards.

So when user clicks card with header text "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY", this value is stored in "txtToDisplay" and becomes the new header text of first card and remaining cards are hidden. Then my lazy column will populate the 1st card with items relevant to this category "PRIVACY, SAFETY & SECURITY".

Same for other cards.

Answer (score 2):

Recompositions take place only on modification of state holders. The docs discourage the use of stuff like `mutableListOf(...)` to store state in your app. You should instead use pre-defined state-holders.

Just change the declaration to

```
var listItemsOpen by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Boolean>()) }
```

The docs:-

_Caution: Using mutable objects such as ArrayList or mutableListOf() as state in Compose will cause your users to see incorrect or stale data in your app.

Mutable objects that are not observable, such as ArrayList or a mutable data class, cannot be observed by Compose to trigger recomposition when they change.

Instead of using non-observable mutable objects, we recommend you use an observable data holder such as State<List> and the immutable listOf()._

Comment: I need to update the value of my list elements based on a click event. How will I update an immutable list ?

Comment: Let us say you wish to add an element. You would do: ```listItemsOpen = listItemsOpen + listOf(element)```

Comment: This is the official way